# RPi 3 Model B+ HDMI not working due to new version of Raspberrypi OS

Tags: hdmi, screen

I've updated my RPi 3 B+ which has been working like a charm for years, but I ended up with a black screen, no HDMI connected message on my TV.

Steps I've follow:

- Download Raspberry Pi Imager.
- Plug in the same SD card.
- Choose Raspbian OS (tried with both Regular and Lite versions).
- Write

It says everything's OK. Then I plug SD card in my RPi, HDMI to the same TV, and the only thing I see is the palette color image for a second or two. Then everything goes black and after a few seconds, my TV shows "No hdmi device connected" message. I tried lots of config.txt tweak combinations with no result.

Then, I started to think that something was broken (Power adapter, HDMI cable, TV, the PI itself...), so I decided to burn a 2018 image of raspbian in the same SD card an everything went back to work again.

**This is obviously a compatibility / default configuration issue**

I would like to know if anybody has the same problem and if there's a solution. I would like to use a newer version of the OS but I cannot make it work on my PI.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Loads of issues on the Raspberry Pi forums. I assume you've tried 'hdmi_safe_mode=1' What resolution is your screen? https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=323281

Comment: Yes, sir. hdmi_safe_mode was the very best thing I did try. Then I turned it off again and started to test different configurations with hdmi_force_hotplug, hdmi_group and hdmi_mode... Until I gave up and performed the version downgrade. The resolution of the raspberry was the default preset. TV supports 4K and is automatically detected once you plug in something. I've made no changes in TV config anyway. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: I would try forcing a 1920x1080 resolution in config.txt